# Data too stale, halting replication

Tags: mongodb, replication

I have an error in MongoDB replication: Data too stale, halting replication. I tried to delete all collections from my databases, but it doesn't work. How can I delete oplog to work my replication? I just need the replication to work.

Thanks.

Comment: read the manual: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/resync-replica-set-member/ removing the collections is not enough, you need to complete clear _all_ data and _then_ perform an initial sync.

Answer (score 4):

You do *NOT* want to delete your oplog. You simply stop your `mongod` process on a secondary, delete the data database files within your secondary's data directory, and then start your `mongod` on the secondary. You then do this on all affected secondaries.

As user Zamnuts pointed out, you should read the MongoDB documented titled "[Resync a Member of a Replica Set](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/resync-replica-set-member/)"

Answer (score 4):

Read the manual: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/resync-replica-set-member removing the collections is not enough, you need to complete clear all data and then [perform an initial sync](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/replica-set-sync/#replica-set-initial-sync).

There are two high-level options (quoted from the manual):

> Restart the mongod with an empty data directory and let MongoDB’s
>   normal initial syncing feature restore the data. This is the more
>   simple option but may take longer to replace the data.

or

> Restart the machine with a copy of a recent data directory from
>   another member in the replica set. This procedure can replace the data
>   more quickly but requires more manual steps.

Answer (score 1):

Stale occurs when MongoDB doesn't have enough oplog to carry away the process.So i suggest two methods:

- Start secondary with new data-dir by `stopping the application writes`, this reduces the oplog growth hence it helps for better initial sync.
- If you dont want to stop application writes you have to `increase the oplog size` that the current size. Oplog size can be calculated on the basis of replication window.

**Increasing oplog:**

Shutdown the primary server

```
use admin

db.shutdownServer()
```

Start primary as standalone & run on different port say 37017

Login to mongo in port 37017

```
mongo --port 37017
```

Remove the old contents in local database

For safety have backop of old oplog before dropping

```
mongodump --db local --collection 'oplog.rs' --port 37017
```

Drop the old contents in local database

```
use local

db.oplog.rs.drop()

db.me.drop()

db.replset.election.drop()

db.replset.minvalid.drop()

db.startup_log.drop()
```

Replset collection cannot be dropped so remove it with required id :

```
db.system.replset.remove({ "_id" : "your_replsetname"})
```

Create a new oplog of required size say 50 GB

```
db.runCommand( { create: "oplog.rs", capped: true, size: (50 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024) } )
```

Also you can specify the oplog size in MB in mongod.conf file,say for 50 GB its 429496 MB

```
replication:
   oplogSizeMB: 429496
```

Hope this Helps !!!